How to output Coverlet code coverage metrics to the console?
When I run dotnet test with Coverlet code coverage, nothing is printed to the console, like it's demonstrated in this answer.
How can I output Coverlet code coverage to the console, so that I can easily check the metrics locally?
➜  dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:ExcludeByFile="**/*Migrations/*.cs" ./src/XYZ.IAM.AssetGovernance.sln
Restore complete (0,4s)
  WorkerExtensions succeeded (1,4s) → src/AssetGovernance/obj/Debug/net8.0/WorkerExtensions/buildout/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.dll
  XYZ.IAM.AssetGovernance succeeded (1,7s) → src/AssetGovernance/bin/Debug/net8.0/XYZ.IAM.AssetGovernance.dll
  XYZ.IAM.AssetGovernance.Tests succeeded (0,1s) → src/AssetGovernance.Tests/bin/Debug/net8.0/XYZ.IAM.AssetGovernance.Tests.dll
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.8.2+699d445a1a (64-bit .NET 8.0.11)
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.07]   Discovering: XYZ.IAM.AssetGovernance.Tests
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.09]   Discovered:  XYZ.IAM.AssetGovernance.Tests
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.09]   Starting:    XYZ.IAM.AssetGovernance.Tests
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.77]   Finished:    XYZ.IAM.AssetGovernance.Tests
  XYZ.IAM.AssetGovernance.Tests test succeeded (1,3s)

Test summary: total: 22, failed: 0, succeeded: 22, skipped: 0, duration: 1,3s
Build succeeded in 3,8s

Packages:
<PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="6.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.12.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.20.72" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.9.2" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.8.2" />

.NET SDK:
9.0.100

